# Jodatime Scala and Serializing Datetimes

Tags: scala, jodatime, apache-spark

I am currently writing a simple program to extract data from a hive DB and I need to use date formats from jodatime... I have something like this:

```
 import org.joda.time._
 import org.joda.convert._
 import scala.tools._
 import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat._
 object DateExtract {
  // change depending on which segment you with wish to catupure, ie weekly, monthly etc.
  def datesBetween(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime): Seq[DateTime] = {
    var daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(startDate.toDateMidnight(), endDate.toDateMidnight()).getDays()
    1 to daysBetween map { startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), _ )} 
    }

  }
```

However when I pull the data into an RDD I am getting an error from this function call that the object it returns is not serializable.

```
 Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$DateExtract$
```

Comment: clarify "pulling data into RDD"

Comment: the datetimes returned from this function point to partitions in the meta store then read the data in those files, then combine it up as a union... everything works fine until a join function at the end of the program on two different RDDs...

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out... basically either you extend the Object like so:

```
object DateExtract extends java.io.Serializable {
  // change depending on which segment you with wish to catupure, ie weekly, monthly etc.
  def datesBetween(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime): Seq[DateTime] = {
    var daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(startDate.toDateMidnight(), endDate.toDateMidnight()).getDays()
    1 to daysBetween map { startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), _ )} 
    }

  }
```

Or simple define only the function:

```
def datesBetween(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime): Seq[DateTime] = {
    var daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(startDate.toDateMidnight(), endDate.toDateMidnight()).getDays()
    1 to daysBetween map { startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), _ )} 
    }
```

Since Spark will serialize functions inherently and apparently not objects... interesting since Jodatime should extend serialization but within the spark scala eco it has to be stated implicitly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but not sure I follow your second solution. How is it different than what you were doing previously?